# I'm looking for a book where an alien with some kind of golden looking organism on him crashes on Earth

Tags: story-identification, aliens

I remember that the ship in which he crashes has the same golden symbols and the feminine lead has to convice her to release him so she could take care of the alien. This golden organism or whatever it is seems to like her and attaches to her in bracelets form or something like this.

Comment: It would help if you could add some more details. Read [How to ask a good story-ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) for suggestions, then edit the additional information into your question.